# "accounting for high fasting blood glucose"- help about the meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have an doubt about the meaning of the words "accounting for high fasting blood glucose".

This is the full sentence:

> "Excess glucose produced by the liver is a major source of high blood
>   glucose in type 2 diabetes, **accounting for high fasting blood glucose**"

As a non-native English speaker, I can understand the following meaning but I'm not sure that this is the right meaning:

"accounting for high fasting blood glucose"- people who account on high sugar levels while they are fasting

Comment: Not quite. *accounting for* = *explaining* and *high fasting blood glucose* = *high blood glucose while fasting*. So: "This is why people with type 2 diabetes have high blood glucose levels when they are fasting".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If hyphens are used to indicate compounding, we get the following phrase:

> accounting for high fasting-blood-glucose

This indicates that the blood glucose levels while fasting are high (The word accounting is used with the meaning of explaining in this context). Linking this with the earlier part of the sentence, we can see that the liver produced that glucose which cause the glucose levels to be high while fasting.